# Error: Could not find or load main class - JAR file

Tags: java, jar

I'm having a problem creating a working JAR file.  I can run my .class file as follows:

```
$ java -cp build/ example.HelloWorld 
Hello World!
```

But running as a jar (from within my build script) fails:

```
java -cp build/ -jar dist/HelloWorld.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class example.HelloWorld
```

I will simplify the problem I'm having by using the simple Hello World project:

```
.
├── build
│   └── example
│       └── HelloWorld.class
├── build.sh
├── dist
│   └── HelloWorld.jar
└── src
    └── example
        └── HelloWorld.java
```

The `class` files need to go into the `build` folder. The JAR file needs to be in `dist` folder. `build.sh` is a bash script that builds the JAR file. Here it is:

```
mkdir -p build && \
mkdir -p dist && \                                         
javac -cp src/ src/example/HelloWorld.java -d build && \
jar -cfe dist/HelloWorld.jar example.HelloWorld build/ && \
java -cp build/ -jar dist/HelloWorld.jar
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
package example;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Running the JAR file as can be seen in `build.sh` results in

```
$ ./build.sh 
Error: Could not find or load main class example.HelloWorld
```

As mentioned, running the application directly works perfectly.

Here is the structure of `HelloWorld.jar`.

```
.
├── build
│   └── example
│       └── HelloWorld.class
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

Contents of `MANIFEST.MF`.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: example.HelloWorld
```

I have been working for like 6 years now with only C and C++. Consider me as a neophyte to Java. I don't really know what I am doing wrong and ran out of ideas to google and try.

Comment: Why are you doing this by hand instead of using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I am starting with java and don't want to jump into it without any underlying knowledge. Basically, trying to do everything manually in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your JAR file is wrong. You must not put the `build` directory in there. It must look like this:

```
.
├── example
│   └── HelloWorld.class
└── META-INF
    └── MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. However, I am doing it right now with `cd build && jar ... && cd ..`. Is there any way to get this directory structure that doesn't involve changing the directory?

Comment: You could use the `-C` option of the [jar tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jar.html). If your project gets bigger you'll want to use a build tool instead of a bash script. De-facto standard build tools for Java are [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/).

Comment: I must have been blind while reading the man page. Thank you very much again.